# How to generate repeating xml elements in Savon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soapui, savon

**soapUI** generates this comment `Zero or more repetitions` in many places in the request XML that it builds. This is part of the XML request.

```
<v1:Attachments>
   <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
       <v1:Attachment>
             <v1:FileName>?</v1:FileName>
             <v1:FileExtension>?</v1:FileExtension>
             <v1:FileContents>cid:1220950351678</v1:FileContents>
       </v1:Attachment>
 </v1:Attachments>
```

I am using **Savon 2.2.0** for communicating with the external service. Ruby `hashes` need unique keys. I tried passing an array of hashes in the format

```
 attachments: [{attachment:
                {file_name: "foo1", 
                file_extension: "bar1", 
                 file_contents:"binary_encoded_content"}}, 
                {attachment:
                {file_name: "foo2", 
                 file_extension: "bar2", 
                 file_contents: "binary_encoded_content"}}]
```

But in this case Savon just does a `to_s` on the array. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
attachments: {
  attachment: [
    {
      file_name: "foo1", 
      file_extension: "bar1", 
      file_contents:"binary_encoded_content"
    }, 
    {
      file_name: "foo2", 
      file_extension: "bar2", 
      file_contents: "binary_encoded_content"
    }
  ]
}
```

Et voila.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Guess, was too tired to see something so obvious. I also found this `Gyoku spec file` which tells the correct hash representations. https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku/blob/master/spec/gyoku/hash_spec.rb