# savon gem SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

I am using savon version-2 gem for soap requests, and for authorization and few other urls I didn't face problem, but for particular endpoint I need to search the date range from and to which needs to be passed inside item so the problem is first item get replaced by second how do i avoid this

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://www.sss.ss/api/v2_soap/?wsdl", log_level: :debug, pretty_print_xml: true, log: true)
session = client.call(:login, message: {username: 'sss', apiKey: 'sss'})
result = client.call(:sales_order_list, message: {sessionId: session.body[:login_response][:login_return], filters: {filter: {item: {key: 'created_at', value: {key: 'from', value: '2016-12-27 00:00:00'}}, item: {key: 'created_at', value: {key: 'to', value: '2016-12-27 23:59:59'}} }}})
```

the xml generated is like with the to value only and i get the error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules

I think overwriting items is the problem How do i send 2 items inside filter

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of problems with my xml, the filter inside the filters is wrong, inside filters i needed to have complex_filter and also while generating camel_case turned to camelCase which showed http 500 error.

For generating arrays of items i followed a comment from this answer [How to generate repeating xml elements in Savon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345486/how-to-generate-repeating-xml-elements-in-savon)

This link i followed
https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku/blob/master/spec/gyoku/hash_spec.rb